# how can I get response returned by Plaid api using script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, plaid

I am trying to connect to the Plaid api using Ruby. But I am trying to connect it using `<script>` tag. I have successfully connected to their api and there is a json object returned in the response as I can see it in browser's console.
But I am unable to get it in my code. My code is

```
    <%= form_for :user, method: :get, :html => { :id => "link-form-id" } do |f| %>
<% end %>

<script
  src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"
  data-client-name="Mandeep"
  data-client-id="**********"
  data-form-id="link-form-id"
  data-key="***********"
  data-product="auth"
  data-env="tartan">
</script>
```

This code returns json object in url as well. I dont understand how can I get it from `<script>` tag.
I have searched all over the web but couldn't get any useful stuff. Can you please help me to find this out. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the method of the form is 'GET' you'll need to parse the query string to retrieve the Plaid Link public_token (so you will want to look for the 'public_token' field in the querystring).